# Why doesn't my custom FlxSprite appear on the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flixel

I created a custom FlxSprite for a fireball by creating a new class(Fireball.as) and typing "extends FlxSprite" after the class name. In the constructor, it calls a function called "shoot()", which directs it to the target and plays a sound:

```
private function shoot():void {
    dx = target.x - x;
    dy = target.y - y;
    var norm:int = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    if (norm != 0) {
        dx *= (10 / norm);
        dy *= (10 / norm);
    }
    FlxG.play(soundShoot);
}
```

Then, I created an array to hold all the fireballs in the game state(PlayState.as):

```
public var fire:Array = new Array();
```

Then in my input() function, when someone pushes the mouse button, it pushes a new Fireball in the array:

```
if (FlxG.mouse.justPressed()) {
    fire.push(new Fireball(x, y, FlxG.mouse.x, FlxG.mouse.y));
}
```

But when I test it, it only plays the sound, but the fireball doesn't show up. I'm guessing that the fireball is somewhere offstage, but how do I fix it?

If it helps, here's the constructor for Fireball.as:

```
public function Fireball(x:Number, y:Number, tar_x:Number, tar_y:Number) {
    dx = 0;
    dy = 0;
    target = new FlxPoint(tar_x, tar_y);
    super(x, y, artFireball);
    shoot();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must add them to stage.

```
if (FlxG.mouse.justPressed()) {
    var fireball:Fireball = new Fireball(x, y, FlxG.mouse.x, FlxG.mouse.y);
    fire.push(fireball);

    // This line needs to be changed if you add the fireball to a group, 
    //  or if you add it to the stage from somewhere else
    add(fireball);
}
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add it to Flixel. Flixel has it's own custom function for adding called `add()`, which is pretty much the Flixel version of `addChild()`. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you post me the code, where Flixel adds it to stage? Sounds may be played without adding to stage, so.

Comment: I changed my comment from before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, the problem was due to not adding the FlxSprite to the Flixel display tree. But also I would advise you to use [FlxObject groups](http://flixel.org/docs/org/flixel/FlxGroup.html) instead of a simple Array.

FlxGroups are **way** better data structure than arrays. For instance they inherit all the methods from a FlxObject, so you can check for collisions directly against the group, also they have specific methods to handle the collection of objects, such as `countDead` and `countAlive` (if you make you of the `alive` attribute), `recycle`, `getFirstDead` and so on.

Check it out, you won't be disappointed. :)